# What feature of Earth would be most likely attract the interest of aliens?

Tags: science-based, aliens, astronomy, earth

What feature of Earth would be most likely to attract the interest of a curious alien intelligence searching the Milky Way marking the Earth as an unusual world and how close would they have to be to detect it?

Assume the alien intelligence has the capabilities of today's humanity in detection technology.

Comment: Well, apparently Mars needs women, or so says https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0060672/

Comment: Emissions from street lighting in the mercury and sodium spectra? They will be looking at street lighting from 20 years back, maybe.

Comment: Are you asking what aspect of Earth would be deemed "most interesting" (opinion based), or what would be the first sign observable from space that there's something different about Earth? Please clarify.

Comment: @Drake By most interesting I mean most unusual and most worthy or a closer look. And as a supplement how far out could that feature be detected from. I would like to create a story where the aliens detect Earth, decide to investigate because of some feature and become more interested as they get closer and more data stacks up. But what do they find out in what sequence as they approach...

Comment: They love a good comedy?

Comment: @Mon Comedy - yes LOL - I wonder what they would make of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUSn9DLWnUU

Comment: Water? It's my impression that we've had enormous luck in having as much water as we do...

Comment: "If Hubble looked at the Earth — from its orbit of approximately 600 km above the earth's surface — this would in theory correspond to 0.3 metres or 30 cm." I can't find the Cosmos episode but iirc you **need to have one meter resolution** to see man's effect on the Earth. The Hubble can barely do that from *orbit*. At less than 200LY (w/o our radio transmissions guiding you), you came here on a whim. "they are likely to detect Jupiter and Saturn first" and with two gas giants clearing the system of rocks; worth a look if you also find a blue planet that is blue *not* because of methane.

Comment: @Mazura I strongly suspect that the presence of an oxygen rich atmosphere could be detected spectroscopically from vastly further away than low earth orbit (although I'm not sure how far). And as for mankind's effect on earth, what about aircraft, super tankers and the hoover dam (for example)?

Comment: "This half-meter resolution image of Hoover Dam, was collected by the GeoEye-1 satellite on January 10, 2009." https://www.satimagingcorp.com/gallery/geoeye-1/geoeye-1-hoover-dam/ - It's immediately identifiable at *half-meter resolution*. - Perhaps it's a question of optics. Would a mirror big enough to 'see' us from outside the solar system, be able to be seen by us in the naked sky.... Say you're just outside the orbit of Pluto; how big a mirror (and/or how many) to get 10m res on the Earth? Pluto is *three* pixels, viewed from the Hubble.

Comment: This question does not have a definite answer, but only the possibility of its answer. Because this question emanated from a land that we have no information about from other observers, which can be the product of all the things on the ground, from the seen and discovered to the unseen and undiscovered, maybe that observer. Methane gas causes some kind of life in him, and oxygen is a poison for him. Also, the conditions of the moment of observation, whether it is time or place, where his feet are, have a lot to do with it. For example, in short, he sees oxygen and says to himself that it is th

Answer (score 34):

**Life**

I'm sure that there are planets with liquid water out there, planets with a human breathable atmosphere out there - regardless of all that - Life would likely be the most interesting thing.

Who are we? How do we act? What do we do? How do we live? How do we die?

There are questions enough about just the Human species that we, ourselves, don't know yet - and so any alien species with a shred of curiosity is going to be interested.

In terms of detection - I'm not sure the distance - but the thing that would most likely cause them to investigate would be non-natural EM spectrum transmissions. Radio waves or similar.

Something with a Mathematical basis.

We can detect EM/F emissions from pretty far away in the Galaxy, so it's possible they could too - the question is isolating our transmissions from naturally occuring noise.

Comment: I actually think they may [detect our atmospheric composition](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jamiecartereurope/2022/08/25/webb-space-telescope-detects-carbon-dioxide-in-an-alien-planets-atmosphere-for-the-first-time/?sh=f3035d942bf2) before they find any radio signals. But yeah, that may be a good way to find life once we (or they) have the telescopes for it! Look for the tell-tale gasses.

Comment: Most man-made radio signals are effectively undetectable beyond a distance of very few light-years; only special-purpose focused beams (such as some kinds of military radar) have a chance of being detectable from father away, and even for those farther away is not really all that far away. The signals we are detecting with our radiotelescopes are produced by enormously energetic phenomena.

Comment: One could specify either 'complex' or 'intelligent' life. Just on Earth we had 5 billion years of life, around 800 million years of complex life and only about 100000 years of intelligent life. We have no idea how representative these numbers are but by definition complex life is a subset of life and intelligent life is a subset of complex life.

Comment: @quarague: Another subset is life that produces a distinct signature, i.e. advanced technological life. That's a much shorter time span.

Comment: @quarague Yeah, my thinking was really "life in general". Even a planet that only hosts some algae is already friendlier (for any kind of surface work) than the majority of planets. (We're still trying to figure out if life bearing worlds are more like 1 in 8 or 1 in a million but either way, a life bearing planet would "attract interest", I suspect.)

Comment: @quarague and the complex life wasn't all that complex for a good chunk of that 800M years.

Comment: @JamieB if Lrrr, ruler of the planet Omicron Persei 8, can watch Single Female Lawyer, then OP's planet can detect The Honeymooners, Jerry Springer and Ally McBeal...

Comment: @RonJohn 700 quintillion planets and nothing on.

Comment: human breathable atmosphere is impossible without life. You need at least microbial life for there to be free oxygen in the atmosphere.

Comment: @AlexP yes, but our detection facilities are TINY. I'd imagine an interstellar-capable alien civilisation to have detection arrays in the size of hundreds of kilometers on the outskirts of their solar systems.

Comment: The 200LY worth of man-made EMF coming from this planet has reached about a quarter million stars. Plug that into the Drake equation and the eight ball will say *please try again* (sample size too small out of 100B).

Comment: @Mazura Plus, my understanding is there may be no way to pick out our signals, even for an advanced civilization. We are drowned out entirely by the sun. It's like having a weak FM transmitter next to a tesla coil. Your signal is there, but no receiver known to science can pick it out of the noise. We have to really bump up our transmission power.

Comment: Sadly given our current knowledge of exoplanets and the conditions necessary for life the probability of a a technically advanced civilization existing anywhere near (within hundreds of light years if not thousands is extremely remote. Add the inverse square law to that picture and the chance of any aliens tuning in to Marconi making his first test radio radio transmissions is extremely remote - almost to the point of zero.

Answer (score 16):

> Assume the alien intelligence has the capabilities of today's humanity in detection technology.

This means that they hardly can detect us. For comparison, we just started to find exoplanets roughly 30 years ago. And most of we found were gas giants. Very few exoplanets Earth-sized or smaller are known. And almost all of the know exoplanets were detected by indirect methods like transit, radial velocity, astrometry, transit time variation or microlensing.

Very few of them were photographed, and all those that were are gas giants presented no more than a small pixelated blob in an image already severely distorted due to the necessity of filtering out the obfuscating star luminosity.

Even looking at [Proxima Centauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri), which is the neighbor next door, the first indications of a exoplanet there came only in 2013 with the confirmation only in 2016. The second and third planets were detected only in 2019 and confirmed only in 2020 and 2022.

So, an alien intelligence would probably don't see us at all with our current level of technology. However, after gaining insight from their first observations, what they would be looking for is exactly what we are looking for, a planet that seems to be capable of life.

And the best way to look for planets that have life is to search for planets that are rocky, have the correct temperature range (i.e. [Goldilocks planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone), not too hot nor too cold) and hint away the presence of water. We know that planets like this can harbor life because Earth is one of those. Gas giants in a Goldilocks position are also candidates for having moons with some life. Surely there could be life out there outside the Goldilocks zone, and even [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars), [Europa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)), [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)) and [Enceladus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enceladus) here around the sun are considered as possibly harboring microscopic primitive life. But what we knows for sure that works are the Earth-twins.

How close they would have to come? With the current technology, except if they are extremely luck to spot a Earth-transit, too close to be viable or realistic, but the technology is increasing very fast.

In fact, they are likely to detect Jupiter and Saturn first. Then, only after much more detailed studies with a lot of observations and luck, they could see Earth. But they would also likely be investigating millions of stars at once and having limited resources for studying them. So, detecting Jupiter and Saturn might be like "meh" for a few decades until the "meh" turns to be a "wow".

Comment: I was thinking of things like detecting Earth has oxygen in its atmosphere or liquid water on its surface or its mass and orbit. The alien intelligence only has our level of detection equipment but they have a very high tech ship that is on its way to Earth. I'm trying to figure out what they can find out about us (and in what order) as they approach Earth from very very far out to LEO.

Comment: @Slarty "has our level of detection equipment but they have a very high tech ship".  That makes no sense... if you have the much-higher tech needed for an interstellar ship, then, as a matter of course, you'll have higher tech detection equipment.

Comment: Well perhaps your right. The trouble is there needs to be a baseline for the detection equipment else the ordering of things will get hopelessly mixed up by people's assumptions about what the aliens can or can't do with their technology. Lets just assume that these aliens emerged into our spacetime continuum and find our electromagnetism a bit different... and it's out of scope...

Comment: @Slarty "detecting Earth has oxygen in its atmosphere or liquid water on its surface" - this is beyond our current level of technology - the hopes so far are in measuring the star spectrum during a transit and try to see how it changes other than just having a plain smaller star luminosity. And with that spectrum difference, try to understand the atmospheric composition of the transiting object. But this is a homeric work, has tiny probabilities of being successful and only worked so far for a handful hot-Jupiters with very crude and unreliable results.

Comment: @Victor Strafusa detecting oxygen in the atmosphere of Earth is very definitely within our capability. The only question is how far away could we detect it? I imagine a fair way out.

Comment: @Slarty Detecting oxygen here on Earth is easy, since we breath. :) But for detecting the atmospheric composition of an exoplanet far away, sorry, for now we can only do that for very large (= gas giant) planets that transits their host star and this only produces a very rough and coarse estimate. So, for detecting oxygen in Earth, the aliens should need to be very close and well-positioned, perhaps even already into the solar system or no more than a few LY in the best case.

Comment: @Slarty [Gliese 1132 b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_1132_b) have an atmosphere for sure, but the scientists are trying to determine which type of atmosphere and so far the results were contradicting and/or inconclusive, but it could be Venus-like. This planet is roughly Earth-sized it is 41.15 LY from here and orbits a faint red dwarf. If that was not enough, this means that the maximum distance for detection of Earth's atmosphere by aliens with our technology is far smaller than 41.15 LY.

Comment: look I'm not arguing that it is not possible to detect oxygen in the atmosphere of a planet 41 light years away. What about 1 light month away or as far away as the orbit of Pluto? How close would they need to be to detect Earth has an oxygen atmosphere?

Comment: @Slarty Hard to know for sure, since we don't have something to do a direct comparison. But likely already inside the solar system. However, it would be significantly farther than Pluto for sure. I think that somewhere in the Oort cloud could be a good guess. The greatest problem is the blinding glare of the Sun and that it is much larger than Earth.

Comment: I think everyone's taking "current technology" too literally. I'm working on instruments for next generation exoplanet spectroscopic surveys right now for missions within the next few decades. We only need incremental improvements to current tech to look at atmospheric composition, not paradigm-shifting leaps

Comment: @thegreatemu So, you are the guy who have the knowledge to post the best answer to this question. Go ahead and beat the current answers (including mine) with something better and I will promptly upvote it.

Comment: Two gas giants are both a prerequisite for finding planets, and keeping the habitable zone safe. Find a water world w/o them and it doesn't really matter; they'll often be hit with giant rocks.

Comment: I have this terrible suspicion that the aliens out there are telling each other that the best way to look for planets with life is to search for planets that are gaseous, have spectral signatures containing the necessary amounts of arsenic and plutonium, and are in the "Goldilocks zone" of 400-700 kelvin...

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Plutonium and arsenic in 400-700 kelvin... Are you searching for something that used to be called Earth and now is post-WW3 Earth?

Comment: @Mazura Nobody knows for sure if Jupiter and Saturn are really necessary since we don't know how diverse life is out there and we already seen a lot of surprises breaking down theoretical planetary models that we had before the era of exoplanets discovery.

Comment: [Orbital resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance) has nothing intrinsically to do with life or exoplanets. The asteroid belt and the Kuiper belt both exist because there are other planets. Not necessarily because there are giants, I can't prove that, but I can tell you what is observed: Life evolved on a planet inside a solar system with the exact specifications of ours. Surprisingly, Jupiter doesn't steal the whole show on that page, but if you've got a better theory for the LHB, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 16):

### Solar eclipse

The sizes of the Sun and the Moon in the sky are almost equal, making solar eplipses possible and especially spectacular. There is no particular reason why this should be the case - we just got remarkably lucky [[link]](https://www.astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2000/10/why-is-the-moon-exactly-the-same-apparent-size-from-earth-as-the-sun-surely-this-cannot-be-just-coincidence-the-odds-against-such-a-perfect-match-are-enormous). (I vaguely remember reading a sci-fi novel where that was a plot point, but I can't recall which one that was.)

Comment: You might be thinking of the novel *Transition*, by Iain M. Banks, which mentions this in the introduction.

Comment: If our aliens believe in God, they might even see it as a sign of intelligent design.

Comment: This may be interesting, curious or funny, but why would they be looking for this?

Comment: But how would they be able to tell this at a distance?  And by this I mean, on Earth the Moon appears to just barely cover up the sun during an eclipse (or not quite, if it's an annular eclipse) but even from orbit it just looks like a dark circle moving across a small part of the Earth.

Comment: @David Yes, I think that's the one!

Comment: @Michael The problem basically boils down to figuring out how big are all the celestial bodies involved, and how big are their orbits. That's the kind of thing we determine for exoplanets all the time. It would probably be a little harder with the moon, and they might need to make some educated guesses about the density of the moon, but that seems doable.

Comment: They might be looking for these if they have eclipses on their world, too.  Eclipses have played important roles in science: they were used to develop spectrography and discover the periodic table of elements, one was used to test Einstein's theory, and the tradition of Greek philosophy itself began when Thales of Miletus used philosophy to predict an eclipse.  If the aliens, similarly, developed science/technology using eclipses, and noted how "lucky" they were, they might be looking for others with the same luck.

Comment: @workerjoe We probably would eventually discover it anyway in other ways if there was no eclipses or even if there was no moon. We wouldn't get stuck in stone age / ancient times / middle ages / whatever age due to that. Further, we could be luckier if Venus had a large moon or it Earth had multiple moons (and possibly Mercury and Venus don't have moons because they were both very unlucky, since they are close to the Sun but not too close for that). So, Earth might be median and not be so lucky after all.

Answer (score 14):

**Free Oxygen in the atmosphere**

Oxygen is a pretty reactive chemical, and free oxygen in an atmosphere would tend to get bound up with other stuff -- for example, it would bond with iron to form "rust" as is the case on Mars.  In order for our atmosphere to have so much free oxygen, something has to be continually producing or freeing up new oxygen.  That's a clue that there's life (specifically, plant life) on this planet.

Comment: Yeah, so that's why they're going to notice us.

Comment: Because there are high levels of oxygen in the atmosphere it marks it as unusual. Our atmosphere is far away from the equilibrium state to be expected.

Comment: @workerjoe without C, H, O & N, *they* aren't going to exist.

Comment: @Slarty advanced, high tech aliens are going to need just as much oxygen in their alien brains as we do in ours.  Thus, they'll think 20% O2 is within a reasonable range.

Comment: @RonJohn Perhaps, but I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying that life will be so common that it would be of no interest to them to detect a probable signature of life on a planet?

Comment: @Slarty I'm saying that workerjoe's answer is poor.  As to how common *advanced* (i.e. agriculture and cities) life is... I'd say it's pretty darned rare.  ***Shockingly and stupendously  rare***, in fact.  Specifically, I think that parameter *f*i in the Drake equation is *rrreeeeeeaaaaalllly* low, given how many factors there are in the probability chain there are that *we* exist (spiral galaxy, not a dead globule; far out in a boring arm, so we're not to close to the center and it's lethal radiation; yellow star, not white hot and short-lived, or dwarfish and not enough energy; (cont.)

Comment: (part 2) planet in the goldilocks zone;  that's not too big or small; another stray proto-planet hits us, forming a moon instead of shattering Earth; the moon doesn't tidally lock the Earth; we don't turn into Venusian hell, and don't get stuck in Snowball; *all* the "right" mutations happen along at "just" the right time for us to evolve; we're not wiped out by the aftermath of the Toba super-volcano eruption 75,000 years ago.... And don't forget that we and our ancestors were stuck in the paleolithic era for **2.4 MILLION YEARS**.  Only 10,000 years ago did we enter the Mesolithic. (cont.)

Comment: (part 3) Thus, **our very existence** is reason for them to be curious about us.

Comment: @RonJohn I tend to agree in that case. It seems likely that detecting oxygen in our atmosphere would be of great interest. The question then is how close do they need to be to detect oxygen in our atmosphere? They are mobile in a spacecraft and could be anywhere. Just trying to see at what point they could say - look at that an oxygen atmosphere - let's have a closer look.

Comment: Well the Drake equation is basically nonsense, but the OP's question was essentially "What would mark our world as an interesting one worth checking out?" and he doesn't say anything about their motivation, but I would assume signs of life would make us "interesting".  An oxygenated atmosphere would not be stable naturally without *something* happening here, hence it would attract attention.

Comment: In *The Cosmos* it says there's a 40% chance per year of global thermonuclear war, so there's a pretty good probability that if you come back in like 10y, you can have the planet free and clear. That that hasn't happened yet ("L") would be the interesting part.

Answer (score 4):

## Plate tectonics

Other answers have covered various aspects of "Earth has life." But what about the big ol' rock herself?

It turns out that Earth is [the only planet](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg19926751-700-unknown-earth-why-does-earth-have-plate-tectonics/#:%7E:text=Earth%20is%20the%20only%20planet,mantle%20%E2%80%93%20will%20be%20too%20thick.) (that we know of) to have plate tectonics. This would be an irresistible curiosity for alien geologists, as subduction zones would contain naturally formed rocks that would be entirely unfamiliar to them.

We were able to observe the crust structure on Venus with [orbital radar](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/magellan/in-depth/) to confirm that it lacks subduction zones entirely. But it's much easier to detect a presence than an absence - sufficiently powerful telescopes should be able to show aliens doing a fly-by that there is something funky going on with Earth to give it all these jagged mountains, and a closer look would be required.

Comment: Plate tectonics might be of interest, but how exactly would they detect such a thing remotely? I imagine studdy from orbit might show some give away signs, but they would have to be very close to detect plate tectonics.

Comment: The distinctive shape of Earth's mountains is visible from afar with good optics, and has no other explanation

Answer (score 1):

This was going to be a response to the answer from @Lyall Stewart in Agreement with @Nosajimiki. but became a bit long.
In the galactic population, are predator or prey species the type that generally evolves to sentience? There is a genera(?) of Sci-Fi where humans are referred to as "Deathworlders" because they are the rare exception to sapiants since usually prey species are the ones who commonly evolve, sometime even more rare, Omnivores.

If the earth was much larger,  achieving the tech necessary to counteract 9.81 m/s² acceleration to leave its gravity well is approaching impossible with chemical rockets.
Thus Just by being born on a ""High G planet" Humans may be among the most physically strong and durable spacefaring sapiants.

We breath one of the most reactive / corrosive elements on the periodic table, Oxygen.

50 to 60 milligrams of nicotine is deadly to a 150lb adult. We consume this substance as regularly and recreationally.

98.6 F (37 C) resting human body temp, is enough to cause serious burns to some species if physically touched.

In less than 8 generations from when humans developed industrialization they were able to destroy the nearly all life on their home planet.

Population expansion ratios are among the highest of native species above 50kg.

Im sure hundreds more examples like these can be suggested for a universe where humans/earth life is exceptional in the universe.

Comment: Fascinating, but what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @Slarty slave labor? Vassal shock troops? Or just squish us before we escape into the wild.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking what might cause aliens on distant worlds take an interest in Earth, of all planets.

The answer is certainly an atmospheric composition that betrays the existence of life. The atmosphere of exoplanets is examined by spectral analysis, which can be done with the proper telescopes. Humans are at the cusp of deploying [telescopes capable enough](https://www.space.com/james-webb-space-telescope-details-exoplanet-atmosphere) of doing that routinely, like the JWST. One answer mentions free oxygen; but *anything* off-balance is a sign for life. [This article](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/10.1089/ast.2017.1729) appears to give a good overview.

---

If, by contrast, you ask what aliens might find interesting once they are here (or what they may find interesting in alien civilizations in general), a number of ideas have been explored in the past:

- In Charles Stross' [*Singularity Sky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_Sky), an entity called *The Festival* drops cell phones from orbit and promises through them: "Entertain us and we will give you anything you want." They are a nomadic intelligence absorbing information and stories.

  I think information, in particular cultural information like songs, texts and images, are the most likely items of value Earth could offer spacefaring civilizations. Additionally, actual material artifacts may have value as well.
- Robe Reid imagines, in his novel [*Year Zero*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_Zero_(Reid_novel)), that by a twist of fate humans are the only race in the universe which is able to produce good music. Terranean music makes aliens ecstatic. It is cult. They name their heavy metals after rock bands: vanhalium, slayerium, megadeathium.

  > "What about bonjovium?" I asked. I've always had a weakness for "You Give Love a Bad Name".
  >  "Of course it exists. But bonjovium is *certainly* not a heavy metal by our standards." Özzy sniffed. "It has an atomic number of just fifty. You call it 'tin'."

  The copyright for the Terranean trove of music is of immeasurable value.
- In the DUST short film [*Final Offer*](https://youtu.be/rv8kOzRZK8g), featuring Anna Hopkins who also appeared in the *Expanse*, the aliens are interested in the water on Earth. Given that part of the water on Earth probably comes from asteroids, it seems easier to harvest those than to siphon it up from the bottom of this gravity well. (But the short is still very well done and entertaining.)

Comment: I do like trying to get a new angle on things. I was trying to develop the idea of something very different from us. Perhaps some sort of complex machine intelligence with a mission to survey star systems, maybe something that emerged into our spacetime from elsewhere with no comprehension of biology. Something that has catalogued hundreds of barren system and then discovers the Earth. The shear novelty and variety of Earth with billions of moving objects swarming over its surface at scales ranging from km (ships) to mm (ants), unnatural transmissions of radio frequencies in all directions.

Answer (score 1):

### Artificial Computer Intelligence.

We don't know if life is anywhere else in the galaxy, however if there is, there is an argument that such life would usually likely be microbial, non-technological life.

Life has been present on Earth for a long time (over 3 billion years), yet only *in the last few dozen years* have computers, and artificial life been possible.

So it is conceivable that Artificial Intelligence may be the unique 'turning point' alien civilisations may be looking for to encounter, or satiate curiosity or to conduct reconnaissance.

Such Artificial Intelligence could manifest itself in terms of transmitting radio, communication via light or some other evidence that causes alien civilisations to now take Earth seriously. Communication with our new AI could be at an amazingly fast, iterative, and improved rate, causing essentially the birth of a new era, influenced by / influencing the Alien Intelligence (which, by the way, may be an AI itself).

Plus it is no secret that AI may inevitably become a dominant force on this planet, and can easily also become a dominant force on all planets in the galaxy, so best to now have a look.

Answer (score 0):

- An arguably sentient species that discovered the [Greenhouse Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_effect) more than a century ago and still argues about environmental protection.
  Consider the uptick of [scripted-reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_reality_television#Scripting_and_staging) shows and a certain brand of daytime talk show, where people watch watch other people who are [even more messed up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_reality_television#As_a_spectacle_of_humiliation) than themselves to feel better about themselves. So the aliens set up really big antenna arrays and big-data signals processing to catch the annual once-in-a-century hurricane mixed with statements from industry lobbyists. (It is arguable if they would get understandable television signals at any distance, but big antennas may help.)
- A species whose ability to hold counterfactual scenarios in their mind goes way beyond "if I climb down from this vegetation, the predactor will catch me, so I won't."
  Mankind produced works like Hamlet, the Lord of the Rings, and E.T. Some of them don't translate to alien audiences, but many do.

Comment: People don't argue about environmental protection because they don't understand the greenhouse effect. People argue about it because the damage to the environment is caused by us living a hedonist life style, and saying that lifestyle is how we should judge the goodness of our society. We have literally built a value system that revolves around how much we consume and throw away.

Comment: @RonJohn, yes, but *thinking* about hypotheticals is on the road to sentience.

Comment: @o.m. yes, I see your point now.

Comment: In order to find out we argue about the greenhouse effect, they would first have to notice our planet at all, notice it has life, then notice it has intelligent life, then notice our transmissions and/or access the internet, and then learn our language ... none of which they would do without their interest being first piqued by something else.

Answer (score 0):

Life on Earth tends towards the aggressive side, where it will destroy rather than assimilate competition.  This can be useful if used correctly.

- We are that strange planet on the edge of the galaxy where monsters live *

Comment: How does an animal assimilate a different species?

Comment: "Destroy rather than assimilate".  Have you seen Britain and the US lately?

Comment: Despite downvotes, I actually really like this answer, not so much because it fits any better than other examples but because Human aggression is a really useful plot mechanism.  Transitioning humans into a dark forest style space community being who knows how far behind on the space race is hard.  But if we are the only ones who spend significant time thinking about how to kill off competition, then we could be the most militarily advanced race in the local cluster and not even know it.

Answer (score 0):

Wood is rarer than gold on a cosmic scale.

Interstellar alien loggers use an alien James Webb Space Telescope and alien ramjets to find, and pillage, oxygen rich worlds. Evolution favours tree analogues on earth-like gravity.

Alien culture mines alien asteroid 16-Psyche; alien metal prices plummet and demand for alien wood increases.

Oxygen would attract their interest. Wood would keep it.

Comment: Why do the aliens care about wood so much?  Lots of things are rare without being valuable.  In the sense of "Aliens care about unique and diverse life forms for their own sake," that's understandable; but wood implies they care about it as a source of fuel (absurd) or building material (unlikely except as a curiosity).

Comment: If I can answer your question with a question: why do humans care about gold so much? wood (analogues) ARE valuable to humanity, and thus, we can assume that any species that evolved on a planet with wood analogues would also find it valuable, especially in a society that has effectively post-scarcity levels of metals.

Answer (score -1):

**Water**

One feature of Earth that is unique among extraterrestrial planets is its abundance of *water*. The Blue Planet is covered in the stuff.

Comment: Yes that might well be of interest lots of liquid water... and how far away would they be able to detect that?

Comment: Humanity has identified about 1,400 exoplanets with significant water; and many of them have WAY more water than Earth does... so not really that rare or meaningful unto itself.

Comment: @Nosajimiki You're right, my fault. I didn't see in the question that they specified the scope was galactic. Within our solar system, on the other hand, we are the only planet with stable oceans on our surface.

Comment: Water is literally one of the top 3 most abundant molecules in the universe. This is the last thing aliens would be attracted to...

Comment: Way to ruin my enjoyment of [The Ice Pirates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_Pirates). Good job everyone. :-(

Comment: This is underrated. We look for liquid water almost exclusively in exoplanets. It's not unreasonable that that would be the thing they detect from a distance, since it implies a planet in the habitable zone (as we understand it).